# Заменяющиеся картинки в зависимости от Поле-всплывающий список

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. Написанию JS я только начал учиться и у меня возникли вопросы.
Написал список вида:

```
function f1()
{
var s = document.getElementById("select");
var t = document.getElementById("a1");
if(s.selectedIndex)
t.style.display = 'inline';
else
t.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<select id="select" onchange = f1()>
<option>Первый вариант</option>
<option>Второй вариант</option>
</select>
<input type="text" style="display:inline" id="a1">
```

При выборе элемента "Второй вариант" появляляется текстовое поле, а при выборе элемента "Первый вариант" это поле не появляляется.
Однако это вариант только для 2 элементов, а как будет выглядеть вариант для 5, т.е. неужели все придется помнить по индексу?
Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе 3-го варианта выводилось графическое изображение?
И если не трудно, приведите пример в полном виде? Просто мне проще разобраться в работе скрипта, имея перед глазами полный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так:

**HTML**

```
<select id="select">
    <option>Первый вариант</option>
    <option>Второй вариант</option>
    <option>Третий</option>
    <option>Четвертый</option>
</select>
<div id="options">
    <p></p>
    <input type="text" id="a1" />
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#options > * {
    display: none;
}
#options > .show {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function () { //ждем  загрузки документа
    var options = document.getElementById("options").children; //взять детей элемента #options

    function f1() {
        var index = this.options.selectedIndex // тут получается индекс выбранного элемента
        for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (i == index) options[i].classList.add('show'); //если то-что выбрано равно номеру дитя - показать
            else options[i].classList.remove('show'); //иначе - скрыть
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("select").addEventListener('change', f1); //на это событие повесить f1

}
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/vYRHg/)

Comment: вот тут немного сокращенное условие, но лучше оставлять развернутый коммент про тернар там используемый (ну и вообще я не уверен что это везде будет работать) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/vYRHg/2/

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло.